# Analysis-Synthesis Reasoning

Tags: logic, definition, proof-theory

In french textbook we use reasoning called analysis-Synthesis

[Raisonnement par analyse-synthèse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raisonnement_par_analyse-synth%C3%A8se) since i didn't find any version of it in english either in wikipedia i will write an explanation here

> You want to find all the solutions of a certain problem (e.g. all the real numbers $x$ such that $x$ is a square). You first start with what's called the analysis : assume you have a solution of your problem (in our example, assume you have a real $x$ such that $x = y^2$ for some $y\in\mathbb{R}$). Then you're going to show that this solution has got a certain property (in our example, that x is positive). Hopefully this property characterizes all the solutions to your problem and the synthesis is about showing that the objects satisfying the previously mentionned property are solutions to your problem (in our example, every positive $x$ is the square of $\sqrt{x}$ so we're done).
>
> **To summarize** : show that every solution is of a certain form, then show that every object of this form is a solution.

Comment: "analyse/synthèse" (analysis/synthesis) is a vocabulary used in signal processing. I never saw it used in this context.

Comment: i just translated the exact french name to english

Comment: Yes but I don't agree with them it deserves an article, since I never heard it.

Comment: The distinction goes back to [Ancient Greek Geometry](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/analysis/index.html#AncConc).

Comment: You can see e.g. Jaakko Hintikka and Unto Remes,  [The Method of Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=XwrvCAAAQBAJ&pg=PR6) (1974)

Answer (score 2):

> To summarize : show that every solution is of a certain form, then show that every object of this form is a solution.

In **mathematical** terminology, this is simply an **equivalence**, which is the same as the conjunction of both forward and backward implications:

> (1) If $X$ is a solution then $X$ satisfies $P$.
>
> (2) If $X$ satisfies $P$ then $X$ is a solution.

And this is **not** a method but rather the very **meaning** of finding **all** solutions to a problem, since it means you want to find a property $P$ such that:

> For every object $X$, ( $X$ is a solution if and only if $X$ satisfies $P$ ).

The forward implication (1) ensures that by using $P$ we will 'find' all solutions. The backward implication (2) ensures that by using $P$ we will 'find' only solutions.

Comment: this is not exactly right.

Equivalence is what you are trying to prove. 

Analyse-synthèse is **a method**. It is a way of reasoning when you want to find some (interesting) P so that "X solution iff P", but **you do not know P**. 

Analyse-synthèse is not a method of proving an equivalence, it's a method for finding an equivalence. (by finding a bunch of necessary conditions, and them trying to prove they are sufficient too)

Comment: @tbrugere: I don't see anything wrong with what I said. In fact, I stated that the two implications are "**not** a method". The *method* is to start from "X is a solution" and try to find some property P such that we can deduce "X satisfies P" (1) and yet P is as strong as possible, and then *hope* that we can also deduce (2). Ultimately the point is that students need to understand that the **goal** of any "solve this equation" kind of question **is** to find such an equivalence, and that how you prove such an equivalence **does not matter**. However, most students do **not** grasp this.

Comment: (By the way, you responded to a post that is more than 6 years old hahaha..)

Comment: I understand what you mean (and that this comment happens way later in the timeline, I wasn't really expecting a response). I was just pointing out that the concept of equivalence is different from what the concept of analyse-synthese is (mostly in case someone stumbled on this post while trying to translate analyse-synthèse). 
what you just called "what the *method* is" in your comment is actually exactly the concept of analyse-synthèse

Comment: @tbrugere: Ok then we are not in disagreement, thanks! =)