# Non-linear differential equation using basic tools

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am supposed to solve a problem, only using a basic lesson on first-order linear differential equations and second-order linear differential equations with constant coefficients.

Here is the problem :

1. **Using this type of reasoning (no equivalent words in english : [raisonnement par analyse-synthèse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2268340/analysis-synthesis-reasoning)), determine all solutions of the differential equation for every open interval** $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ : $y' = \dfrac{1+y^2}{1+t^2}$
2. **Determine the solution whose representative curve go through the point of coordinates $(0,1)$.**

My reflexion and limits :

- the function $t \mapsto t$ is a trivial solution to the equation ;
- As this differential equation is not linear, the superposition principle is unfortunately not applicable ;
- I tried to derive the equation to find a linear differential equation, but I did not suceed ;
- I saw on the Internet that this is considered as a Riccati equation but I am not supposed to have any knowledge of it ;
- the website [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/) can solve it, but does not show how. : solutions are supposed to be all functions defined by $t \mapsto \tan(\alpha + \arctan(t))$ with $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ ;
- As $\tan(\alpha + \arctan(t)) = \dfrac{B+t}{1-Bt}$ with $B = \tan(\alpha)$, I tried to verify those functions are solutions but did not find so (assuming I made no mistake).

Thanks for helping

Comment: Seems so obvious now... Thank you !